# How to Add Icon to a Excel Menu/Toolbar Button

Tags: excel, vba

I need to add a image to a custom toolbar/menu item which is create through VBA.

For a toolbar item, I tried following code

```
Set NewBtn = TBar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
With NewBtn

.Picture = LoadPicture("mypic.bmp")
.OnAction = "'MyFunction""" & para1 & """'"  //VBA Function
'.Caption = "MyFunction"
.TooltipText = "MyFunction"
.Style = msoButtonCaption

End With
```

In the above code LoadPicture() does not seem to be working. My toolbar is initializing at the workbook load up event. I noticed that the image is loading to the toolbar button, but in a fraction of second it disappears and only item text is displayed. My image is 16x16 pixel bmp one.

Any help appreciate to get around this problem

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use `MsoButtonStyle.msoButtonIcon` or one of the `MsoButtonStyle` members that contain the word *Icon*.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA I store the icons on a worksheet (oTemplate) and transfer them to the buttons using:


`with NewBtn 

oTemplate.Shapes("picCalcOpt").CopyPicture


.PasteFace`